# WEB API 2 OAuth Client Credentials Authentication, How to add additional parameters when some errors occured?

Tags: authentication, oauth, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I am developing WEB API with token based authentication. The client will send me the username, password, and the grant_type to get the access_token. I am able to add some additional parameters when the authentication is successful. But, I also want to add some additional parameters when it is failed. Right now, I only can send the error and error_description as the response.

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "User did not confirm email."
}
```

When the claim is validated, i can use this code to add parameters to the response.

```
ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, "JWT");
var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
     {
          "Status", "Success"
      }
});
var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, props);
context.Validated(ticket);
```

How can achieve the same thing when it is error?

```
context.SetError("invalid_grant", "User did not confirm email.");
```